# Font size on Excel charts different on different PC

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, charts

I have two PCs which both can access an Excel spreadsheet (on OneDrive). Both PCs have font scaling set to 100%.
But when I format a chart on one PC with reasonable size fonts, on the other PC text looks HUGE, and when I fix it there it looks extremely small on the other PC.
The numeric values for the font sizes (like 7pt) are the same on both PCs, yet somehow Excel interprets them differently, depending on PC. NB that the fonts on the spreadsheets themselves are OK on both PCs. It's only charts which seem affected.

Any ideas how to get both PCs to agree with each other?

Comment: If by _NB that the fonts on the spreadsheets themselves are OK on both PCs._ you mean that you have ensured the font that Excel is using is installed on both machines, have you tried copying that font from one PC to the other? Sometimes even fonts which have a similar-sounding name may slightly differ.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the DPI setting for 2 PCs and confirm if the system language is the same.